# Issue while redirect from one page to another

Tags: django

I am using DJango 2.2.6

**Profile App**

```
app_name = 'myprofileapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile', accountController.as_view(), name='account')
]
```

**Auth App**

```
app_name = 'authapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login', loginController.as_view(), name='login')
]
```

**Below is the code to login user. In case logged in successfully then sends to profile page.**

```
class loginController(View):
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        userobj = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if(userobj == None):
            return HttpResponse("Not Found")
        else:
            login(request, userobj)
            return redirect('profile')
```

After this code `login(request, userobj)` if I write `return render(request, 'profile.html')` then the url remains login.

and when I write `return redirect('profile')`, it says

> Reverse for 'profile' not found. 'profile' is not a valid view
>   function or pattern name.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path('profile', accountController.as_view(), name='profile')
```

change`name='account'` to `name='profile'`

Comment: hi, Many thanks for the answer. My code is not working without this code `return redirect('myprofileapp:profile')` it is presently written as `return redirect('profile')`

Comment: so yes those two things together are needed

Comment: can you suggest something here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790186/error-when-fetching-the-logged-in-user-details

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the `app_name` as well, and since you named the view `'account'`, use that name:

```
class loginController(View):
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        userobj = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if(userobj == None):
            return HttpResponse("Not Found")
        else:
            login(request, userobj)
            return redirect('myprofileapp:account')
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add the app_name while redirecting. Please change the redirect parameter like this

```
return redirect('myprofileapp:account')
```