# Error when fetching the logged in user details

Tags: django

I am using Django 2.2.6.

**Login Code**

```
class loginController(View):
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        userobj = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if(userobj != None):
            login(request, userobj)
            return redirect('myprofileapp:profile')
```

Once the user is authenticated, navigated to profile page. When this line executes `if(request.user.is_authenticated):`, I get an error.

```
class accountController(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if(request.user.is_authenticated):
            return HttpResponse(request.user)
```

> 'User' object is not iterable

**Edit 1**

```
class accountController(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if(request.user.is_authenticated):
            print(request.user.username)
            return HttpResponse("ok")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("not ok")
```

nothing is printed. Just ok got printed in above code.

Comment: What are you expecting `HttpResponse(request.user)` to do?

Comment: I am trying to print the logged in user details.

Comment: Then you need to convert it to a string. Most probably, you should render a template.

Comment: If you want to print the logged in user details, then you have to do like this:-

print(request.user.username)

Comment: I tried this line of code: `print(request.user.username)`  but nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
return HttpResponse(request.user)
```

You can pass in a string to `HttpResponse`. You are passing `request.user` which is an object. Since the user name is a string you can do something like:

```
return HttpResponse( request.user.username)
```

Basically whatever string you pass to `HttpResponse` will be shown in in the browser. You pass "ok", ok will be printed, you pass "Pankaj",  Pankaj gets printed. You pass `request.user.username` which is a string, that username gets shown in the browser as response.

Putting something in `print` prints to your django console, it does not print to your web browser.

Comment: In my edit section, I tried your approach. But, it only prints **ok**. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You should not `return HttpResponse(request.user)`, as it is not an iterable object. It is just a SimpleLazyObject of AuthenticationMiddleware.

Comment: I added the code and updated the question, please check. But, still nothing is printed. Just **ok** got printed

Answer (score -2):

instead of `if(request.user.is_authenticated):` try this `if request.user.is_authenticated():`

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. Check the official docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users

Comment: no it is not you did not mentioned django version you using django provide both option using is_authenticate as attribute or is_authenticate() as function 

try to return your HttpResponse(str(request.user),content_type='text/plain')